# Twitter APIにおけるApiResponseError: Request failed with code 401エラーの解消

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

### 解決したい内容

Twitterの特定ハッシュタグがついた投稿をdiscord.jsでスラッシュコマンドを実行した際に取得しランダムに返す際発生するエラー「ApiResponseError: Request failed with code 401」を解消したい。

### エラーログ

```
Error fetching tweets: ApiResponseError: Request failed with code 401
    at RequestHandlerHelper.createResponseError (/rbd/pnpm-volume/d9af4806-06c4-4055-abaa-95683c0ef89c/node_modules/twitter-api-v2/dist/cjs/client-mixins/request-handler.helper.js:104:16)
    at RequestHandlerHelper.onResponseEndHandler (/rbd/pnpm-volume/d9af4806-06c4-4055-abaa-95683c0ef89c/node_modules/twitter-api-v2/dist/cjs/client-mixins/request-handler.helper.js:262:25)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:538:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1345:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  error: true,
  type: 'response',
  code: 401,
  headers: {
    perf: '7469935968',
    'content-type': 'application/problem+json',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0',
    'content-length': '99',
    'x-transaction-id': 'd8afd444d7c03df6',
    'x-response-time': '1',
    'x-connection-hash': '0a0dec5ffb6e1f05b8cd322b349588ceb48b298a421bfe5b890f3d169aff5dbc',
    date: 'Sat, 23 Mar 2024 16:08:52 GMT',
    server: 'tsa_b',
    connection: 'close'
  },
  rateLimit: undefined,
  data: {
    title: 'Unauthorized',
    type: 'about:blank',
    status: 401,
    detail: 'Unauthorized'
  }
}
[]
No tweets found.
```

### ソースコード

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const { Intents } = require('discord.js');
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const TwitterApi = require('twitter-api-v2').TwitterApi;
require('dotenv').config({ path: '../.env' });
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const {
  Client,
  GatewayIntentBits: {
    Guilds,
    GuildMessages,
    MessageContent
  },
  Collection,
  Events,
  GatewayIntentBits,
  Partials,
  Permissions
} = require("discord.js");

const client = new Discord.Client({ 
  'intents': [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, 
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers, 
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildEmojisAndStickers, 
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildIntegrations, 
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates, 
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences, 
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, 
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions, 
    GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages, 
    GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessageReactions, 
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent
  ], 
  'partials': [
    Partials.User, 
    Partials.Channel, 
    Partials.GuildMember, 
    Partials.Message, 
    Partials.Reaction
  ],
});

const twitterClient = new TwitterApi({
  clientId: process.env.clientId,
  clientSecret: process.env.clientSecret,
  bearerToken: process.env.bearerToken,
});

const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');

async function getTweetsWithHashtag(hashtag) {
  try {
    const tweets = await twitterClient.get(`https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query=%23(ここにタグ名が入る)&max_results=10`);
    console.log('Tweets:', tweets.data);
    return tweets.data; // Twitter APIからのレスポンスを返す
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching tweets:', error);
    return []; // エラー時は空の配列を返す
  }
}

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('search')
    .setDescription('ツイート取得'),

  async execute(interaction) {
    try {
      const tweets = await getTweetsWithHashtag('(タグ名)');
      console.log(tweets);

      if (tweets.length > 0) {
        // ツイートが取得できた場合の処理
        const randomTweet = tweets[Math.floor(Math.random() * tweets.length)];
        console.log(randomTweet.text);
        // ツイート情報を埋め込み形式で作成
        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
          .setColor('#FFE201')
          .setTitle('Random Tweet')
          .setDescription(randomTweet.text)
          .addField('Author ID', randomTweet.author_id)
          .addField('Posted At', new Date(randomTweet.created_at).toUTCString());

        await interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] });
      } else {
        // ツイートが取得できなかった場合の処理
        console.log('No tweets found.');
        await interaction.reply('No tweets found.');
      } 
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching tweets:', error);
      await interaction.reply('Error fetching tweets');
    }
  },
};
```

### 試した内容

ChatGPTやBing AI等を用いて、

```js
const twitterClient = new TwitterApi({
  clientId: process.env.clientId,
  clientSecret: process.env.clientSecret,
  bearerToken: process.env.bearerToken,
});
```

の部分の変更を試しました。

- TwitterのAPIに問題が生じていると考え、使用するアカウントを変更しました。
- トークンのリセットを試しました。
- Developer Portalの「App info」のURLを入れる箇所に適当にURLを入れてみましたが、入れなかったときと変わりませんでした。

### Twitter APIでの権限の設定

[image: 権限設定]

【追記】teratail、qiitaにおいても質問をしています。
https://teratail.com/questions/dqc61u6a7o1huq
https://qiita.com/ssmn93/questions/1c08e39769cb499d85a5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP レスポンスコード 401 はクライアントエラー Unauthorized を示し、API にリクエストしている側の問題によってうまく認可できていないことを表します。

実際、今回の問題はコードの側で Twitter API の認証認可がうまくできていないところです。Twitter API はいくつかの認証方法を用意していますが、いまのコードだとそのどれを実装しようとしているのかが曖昧になっているように見受けられます。今回の場合ツイートの検索をなさりたいようなので、[ドキュメント](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/api-reference/get-tweets-search-recent)に書かれているようにたとえば OAuth 2.0 の app only authentication を使うのが最初は簡単です。

OAuth 2.0 App-only を使う場合にどのように実装すれば良いかは、node-twitter-api-v2 のドキュメントに書かれています。以下のあたりを参考にしてください。

- Basics https://github.com/PLhery/node-twitter-api-v2/blob/1.16.1/doc/basics.md
- Authentication https://github.com/PLhery/node-twitter-api-v2/blob/1.16.1/doc/auth.md
- Search tweets (recent) https://github.com/PLhery/node-twitter-api-v2/blob/1.16.1/doc/v2.md#search-tweets-recent

なお、この問題は discord.js とは全く関係がありません。なので、Twitter API 用のクライアントを初期化してツイートを取得する処理の部分のみを抜き出してみて、まずはそれがうまく動くように直してみてください。そうすることで問題を各個撃破できます。参考: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: ありがとうございました。教えていただいたgithubを参考にプログラムを変更した所、401エラーは解消しました。続けて403エラーが発生しましたので、改めて質問を作成します。